# Using @Autowired field in component implementing the same interface

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

Can I be sure that delegate field in the class SomeInterfaceAdvancedImpl (see the code below) will always be of type of SomeInterfaceBasicImpl. 
I just checked the type in debugger and it worked, but I have doubts, that it will always work in the same way. Can someone please explain the phenomenon (why it works)?

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    long doSomething(String param);
}

public abstract class SomeInterfaceAbstractImpl implements SomeInterface {
    public abstract long doSomething();
}

@Component
class SomeInterfaceBasicImpl extends SomeInterfaceAbstractImpl {
    @Override
    public long doSomething(String param) {
      return 1;
    };
}

@Primary
@Component
class SomeInterfaceAdvancedImpl extends SomeInterfaceAbstractImpl {

    @Autowired
    SomeInterface delegate;

    @Override
    public long doSomething(String param) {
      if (param == "2") {
        return 2;
      } else {
        return delegate.doSomething(param);
      }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add some other implementation of `SomeInterface` and you'll see the Spring error caused by `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`. In that case you'll need to use `@Qualifier` annotation to tell Spring which bean to use.

See this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-autowiring-qualifier-example/) at mkyong.com for better understanding.

Comment: That is not a compile error. `@Qualifier` does not state which implementation to use, it states which bean to use. It's an important distinction.

Comment: You're right. Little bit too fast typing and answering. I'll edit that.

Comment: @shx although your answer adds more observations and details, it does not answers to me, why `@Primary @Component` does not autowire itself, and takes another implementation. And, yet, will not work when one more implementation will be added.